# What is the safest method to make session?

Tags: node.js, express

So I have few things to say I don't want to use cookies so things like express-session doesn't come as option.

I use nodejs with express with no front-end JavaScript and mysql as database. I don't really know how to do it so I would like to hear your opinion.
I already tried to search on internet.

Comment: Other systems that offer cookie-less sessions generally do so by appending a session token to every URL.  Which gets cumbersome quickly.  Basically to use a session the server needs to know that any given request is part of that same session, so each request needs to include a value identifying the server-side session.  If you can't use cookies, what *can* you do to provide the server with that value on each request?  Taking a step back... Why can't you use cookies?  Why do you need sessions?  What functionality are you trying to build?

Comment: @David Basically I want to make login system, and i need user to stay logged in until they logout eider via log out button or just by closing the window. I don't want to use cookies because I want to make this app also accessible for tor based browsers so cookies are not an option for me.

Comment: @IDontKonow What Tor browser are you referring to which doesn’t support cookies…? I’m not aware of one that simply doesn’t allow cookies at all, at least by default. Separately, clients with cookies turned off entirely are extremely rare, and usually are run by users understanding that this type of functionality simply won’t work in most cases. Unless there is another requirement driving this design decision, this restriction seems quite superfluous and making your job harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 5):

When dealing with regular web pages, there are only four places in a request to store information that would identify a session.

1. Cookie sent with each request
2. Custom header on each request
3. Query parameter with each request
4. In the path of the URL

You've ruled out the cookie.

The custom header could work for programmatic requests and is regularly used by Javascript code with various types of tokens.  But, if you need a web browser to maintain or send the session on its own, then custom headers are out too.

That leaves query parameters or in the path of the URL.  These both have the same issues.  You would create a sessionID and then attach something like `?sessionID=92347987` to every single request that your web page makes to your server.  There are some server-side frameworks that do sessions this way (most have been retired in favor of cookies).  This has all sorts of issues (which is why it isn't used very often any more).  Here are some of the downsides:

1. You have to dynamically generate every single link in a web page so that it will include the right sessionID as part of the link so if the user clicks on it, the resulting http request will have the right sessionID included.
2. All browser caching has to be disabled or bypassed because you don't want the browser to use cached web pages that might contain the wrong sessionID.
3. User bookmarks basically don't work because they end up bookmarking a URL with a sessionID in it that won't last forever.
4. The user sees `sessionID=xxxx` in all their URLs.
5. Network infrastructure that log the URLs of requests will include the sessionID (because it's in the URL).  This is considered a security risk.

All that said and with those tradeoffs, it can be made to work, but it is not considered the "safest" way to do it.